# C - Sending a PIPE FD, that was created in a thread, to the parent process through a FIFO

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, unix

I'm trying to create a small server for a chat app, using internet domain sockets. The server is composed of a dispatcher and a main-server.

The dispatcher is in charge of detecting new connection requests and handling them in a new thread. This thread sends information to the main-server through a FIFO. The bundle sent by the thread has a pipe FD that it created, so that the main-server can communicate back with the response. The dispatcher was initialised by the main-server with fork and then using *execve()*.

The problem is that I can't write data to the pipe from the server. I get the **[EBADF Bad file descriptor]** error.

I understand that I'm supposed to pass the pipe FD from the parent process to a child process, but this solution doesn't work for me because I don't know how many pipes I'm going to need at the same time. Moreover, I don't want to create a FIFO for each thread, this means I would need to create a new file for every thread that is active and I think this not a very elegant solution.

So to summarize:

- Is it possible to use pipes in this manner?
- If the problem is with
  the use of pipes, why can't I pass the pipe FD through a FIFO and use
  it in another process? I read that it was possible to communicate
  between unrelated processes with pipes by using UNIX domain sockets
  to pass the FD. What is the difference between these approaches?
- What solution would you recommend?

Comment: There's a mechanism to pass file descriptors over socket connections; it is not adaptable to other communications mechanisms such as FIFOs.

Comment: I've added the "unix" tag since this seems to be about unix programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the dispatcher from the main server with `fork` it won't share the file descriptor table: the dispatcher will initially get a copy of the file descriptors, but any files or sockets the dispatcher opens afterwards will be open only in the dispatcher.

To create the dispatcher you should use a method that shares the file descriptor table. For example you can use a `pthreads` thread. If you use Linux you can replace `fork` with the low level [`clone`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) function, including  `CLONE_FILES` in the flags.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Joni. I now understand that the problem is that each process have different file descriptor tables, therefore the same fd descriptor number on each one references a different resource, hence the pipe can't be used in this manner, unless the underlying fd table is modified. I'm using OSX so I think clone() is unavailable. Is it possible to spawn new threads from a thread?

Comment: On OS X you can use pthreads or Cocoa threads, see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/AboutThreads/AboutThreads.html

Answer (score 1):

You can only transfer open file descriptors between two processes on the same machine via a 'Unix domain' (local domain, as opposed to IPv4 or IPv6) socket.  The type of file descriptor that is transferred may be any valid file descriptor, but the transfer mechanism has to be a Unix domain socket file descriptor using [`sendmsg()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sendmsg.html) in the process that already has the file descriptor open and
[`recvmsg()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recvmsg.html) in the process that is gaining access to a descriptor (though most of the information needed is buried in the description for [`<sys/socket.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html)).